# jQuery AJAX call to post a message - ERROR Out of stack space

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'am trying to create a form which you can fill out where you post a message and it gets printed to the screen through jQuery ajax. Rest of the messages are taken from the database and printed to the screen in the same manner. Im getting the error 'Out of stack space', and as i am a 100% beginner with this i cannot find the issue.

Here is the form, code to take messages from the database, and also the jquery ajax call.

```
    <form class="guestbook">
        <label for="yourName" id="guestbook">Ditt namn:</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="yourName" id="yourName" placeholder="Namn" required>
        <br />
        <textarea type="text" id="yourReview" name="yourReview"></textarea>
        <br />
        <input value="Skicka" type="button" id="send-btn" name="send-btn"></input>
    </form> 
    <!-- Här visas alla inlägg -->
    <div class="guestOutput">
        <?php
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Messages ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 5";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die ('Kunde inte ta fram meddelanden');

            while($ms = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)){
                echo "<p class='allmsgs'>" . $ms['name'] . "<br>" . $ms['review'] . "<br> Postat: " . $ms['postad'] . "</p>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $("#send-btn").click(function(){
        var name = $("#yourName").val();
        var msg = $("#yourReview").val();

        //Ajax call
        $.ajax({
            method:"POST",
            url: "../php/postmsg.php",
            data:{name: name, msg: msg}
        }).done(function() {
            $(".guestOutput").prepend($("<p class='allmsgs'>" + name + "<br>" + msg + "<br> Postat: Precis nu..." + "</p>").fadein(300));

            $("#yourName").val("");
            $("#yourReview").val("");
        });
    });
</script>
```

HERE is the php file which stores the information in the database:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['guestName']) && (isset($_POST['yourReview']))){
    $rvw = $_POST['yourReview'];
    $nm = $_POST['yourName'];
    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO Messages(name, review) VALUES ('$nm', '$rvw');";

    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1) or die ("Något gick fel vid uppladdning av ditt meddelande, försök igen");
}
?>
```

I have more experience with php so i dont Think there are any issues with the database functionality.

BTW. First i got the error 'function uploadMessage is not defined' - So first i had a function called uploadMessage, then a 'onclick' on the button. I removed this and instead tried using $("#send-btn").click, which obviously did not solve my issue. But maybe it could have something to do with that?

My issue is now solved with your help. Thank you, and as to fixing the problem of not Printing the corrent information to the screen when a message is posted, i just got the values from the form again, $("#yourName").val() etc.

Comment: `data:{name: yourName, msg: yourReview }` should be `data:{name: name, msg: msg }`

Comment: where does said error occur? i don't see anything in your code that could cause that.

Comment: Okay @devlincarnate, the error occurs in the console once i try to 'send¨' a new message to be stored in db and printed to the screen

Comment: @KevinB, see my answer above

Comment: @devlincarnate i made those Changes and im not instead getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).done is not a function", why is not that working, i have jquery included properly

Comment: @DouglasPettersson, $.ajax().done is using the promise/jquery deferred structure, which may not be supported in your version of jQuery, read http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `success` instead of `done` function.

```
$.ajax({
  method: "xx",
  url: "xx",
  data: {xx},
  success: function(){
    //done function
  }
});
```

> An alternative construct to the `success` callback option, the `.done()`
> method replaces the deprecated `jqXHR.success()` method.

Comment: Thank you, this basically solved my issue, although, now when i post a message, i dont  get the msg and name as i want, instead i get 'success' printed. I switches places on the var's, so now i get                             [object HTMLInputElement]
[object HTMLTextAreaElement]

Comment: [object HTMLInputElement] [object HTMLTextAreaElement] means you pass the objects. use .val() to get the value and resend them.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing RAM of the machine you're in or restart the machine. The stack has to do with memory of the machine, not with jQuery.